# How to fix my Fivestar widget rendered in a template file?

Tags: theming, rating

I have the [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module installed and have made one of my node field as a Fivestar field. Now I am rendering this field in a template file.

```
  $settings = array(
              'content_type' => 'node',
              'content_id' => $variables['nid'],
              'entity' => $variables['elements']['#node'],
              'stars' => 5,
              'field_name' => 'field_rating',
              'autosubmit' => TRUE,
              'allow_clear' => FALSE,
              'langcode' => $node_language,
              'text' => 'none',
              'tag' => 'vote',
              'style' => 'average',
              'widget' => array( 'name' => 'oxygen', 'css' => drupal_get_path('module', 'fivestar') . '/widgets/oxygen/oxygen.css' )
              );
  global $user;
  $fivestar_values = fivestar_get_votes('node', $variables['nid'], 'vote', $user->uid);
  $render_form = drupal_get_form('fivestar_custom_widget', $fivestar_values, $settings);
  print render($render_form);
?>
```

The fivestar field works fine with the only exception that when there are no votes, it shows 4 stars out of five as pre-selected. But once I cast one vote it behaves properly for all users.

How to fix this?

Comment: You say you are doing this in a tpl, but what tpl? Where are you trying to print the fivestar widget?

Comment: I am printing this in various template files like this node's tpl, a views style output tpl etc. Does this help?

Comment: Well if it is a field on the content type and you are in a node tpl why not just print the field as usual instead of all the custom stuff?

Comment: Rendering the field in a normal way like `print render($content['field_vote']);` renders the stars but users are not able to cast votes. Apparently it comes in a disabled state. But when I render them like the way I have shown in my question it works fine in regards to the vote casting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some headbanging I found that it was occurring due to the "tag" attribute. Generally for each node type, its better to create its own tag, and that would fetch you the correct result. I was using the 'vote' tag of another content type. Hence the problem.

Hope this helps someone...